# How to use a loop to print a statement a number of times defined by user inputs on visual basic

Tags: vba

I would like to make a simple program that does the following

Takes a text input of a string and the number of times it needs to be looped by the program user and produces that loop to output that string the number of times stated. My loop isn't doing that. (New to visual basic loops)

Kindly correct advise where i have gone wrong below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub cmdLoop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdLoop.Click
        Dim newput As String
        Dim numberr As Integer
        Dim counter As Integer

        newput = txtStatement.Text
        numberr = TxtRepeatNum.Text

        For counter = 1 To numberr
            lbloutput.Text = newput & vbCrLf
        Next
        

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is writing *numberr* times the same string into the text box, with every iteration it overwrites the previous content. Change it to

```
lbloutput.Text = ""
For counter = 1 To numberr
    lbloutput.Text = lbloutput.Text & newput & vbCrLf
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @FunThomas, it would mean that for loops involving strings the source of the text would need to be declared as = "" before the loop to ensure it works? 

Many thanks once more.

Comment: If you don't reset it, it will keep it's old content at the beginning (because it's not overwritten). Alternative is to use an intermediate variable.